# How can I upgrade an iPhone app to iPad app in xcode 4.2?

Tags: ios, universal-code

I have upgraded my iPhone app to universal by right right clicking the project target and selecting duplicate option. Then there was 2 choices-duplicate only and 'duplicate and transition to iPad'. I choose second one. Then a group of iPad XIB files(having same name as iPhone XIBs) called Resources_iPad is automatically added to the app. But still when I choose iPad simulator to run the project, the app chooses only iphone XIBs. Can anyone help me to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

go to target (or project) settings and check if `Targeted Device Family` set to `iPhone/iPad`

Comment: even when I set this, app loads autoresized iPhone XIBs for iPad. But not the new XIBs

Comment: @vijj did you use ~ipad as the postfix of your xib-names?

Comment: @Till no.they are XIBs with same name as iPhone XIBs and are generated when i choose 'duplicate and transition to iPad' as i said.a copy-Info.plist is also generated. Since the app itself generated the XIBs with same name, i can't select nibname via code.

Comment: one way i found is to rename the xibs by adding -iPad and select different nib names for ipad and iphone. but the app itself gave these  names, i thought there is some simpler way to do this.. that is why asked

Comment: @viji The exact same name? That will most likely not work - check for warnings when building. And again, use the proposed postfix to get them automatically chosen by your app.

Comment: @Till There are no warnings/errors since they are autogenerated. I will continue using the prefix for this project. Please inform me if there is any other way to do this. Thanks for your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Any XIBs loaded in code will still load the iPhone version. You should use `UIUserInterfaceIdiom()` to determine which XIB to load. Also make sure you have correctly set your iPad interface file in Info.plist if you specify your iPhone one there.

Comment: Since the app itself generated the XIBs with same name, i can't select nibname via code

Comment: one way i found is to rename the xibs by adding -iPad and select different nib names for ipad and iphone. but the app itself gave these names, i thought there is some simpler way to do this.. that is why asked